# Batch file IF ELSE fails

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I'm configuring to check if the user whose logged in is a specific user or not. No matter what I do the batch file always crashes on the `) ELSE (` line. I've spent five hours on this and I've definitely shrunk and improved the commands over what they were, but it's still not working. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how I can get it to work (also, if I'm doing plainly stupid, let me know, I'm kind of a dummy when it comes to batch files):

```
@ECHO OFF
::
SETLOCAL
::
IF "%USERNAME%" EQU "jdoe" (
    IMDISK -a -s 32M -m #: -p "/FS:exFAT /Q /Y /V:MERGEABLES"
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D IN ('WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE "size=33538048" GET Name /format:value'^) DO (
        COPY "\\WIN2K8R2-F-01\Remote Applications\Batches\Merge PDFs.lnk" "%%D\Merge PDFs.lnk"
        GOTO End
    ^)
) ELSE (
    IMDISK -a -s 256M -m #: -p "/FS:exFAT /Q /Y /V:RAMDRIVE"
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D IN ('WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE "size=268304384" GET Name /format:value'^) DO (
        COPY "\\WIN2K8R2-F-01\Remote Applications\Batches\Archive Folders.lnk" "%%D\Archive Folders.lnk"
        GOTO End
    ^)
)
::
:End
::
IF EXIST "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.exe" (
    "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.exe" "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.bgi" /Timer:0 /AcceptEula /Silent
)
::
ENDLOCAL
```

**UPDATE**

So, I rewrote my version and honestly I don't see much difference between my original and the rewrite, but the rewrite worked. However, in the end I can't use this script because of one issue courtesy of Microsoft. The issue is that normal users are not allowed to format drives. That throws `IMDISK` out the window and now I'll have to mess with hidden folders and shortcuts, etc. `RUNAS` doesn't help and I couldn't get it to work anyway. I'm pretty sure I messed it up, but I don't see the point in pursuing a fix anymore. For anyone who cares, here's the final version of the script. Maybe it will help someone else:

```
@ECHO OFF
::
IF /I "%USERNAME%" EQU "jdoe" (
    IMDISK -a -s 32M -m #: -p "/FS:exFAT /Q /Y /V:MERGEABLES"
::
    TIMEOUT 4
::
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D IN (
        'WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE "size=33423360" GET Name /format:value'
    ) DO (
        PUSHD %%D
::
        COPY "\\WIN2K8R2-F-01\Remote Applications\Batches\Merge PDFs.lnk" "Merge PDFs.lnk"
::
        POPD
::
        GOTO End
    )
) ELSE (
    IMDISK -a -s 256M -m #: -p "/FS:exFAT /Q /Y /V:RAMDRIVE"
::
    TIMEOUT 4
::
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D IN (
        'WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE "size=268304384" GET Name /format:value'
    ) DO (
        PUSHD %%D
::
        COPY "\\WIN2K8R2-F-01\Remote Applications\Batches\Archive Folders.lnk" "Archive Folders.lnk"
::
        POPD
::
        GOTO End
    )
)
::
:End
::
IF EXIST "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.exe" (
    "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.exe" "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.bgi" /Timer:0 /AcceptEula /Silent
)
```

One thing I couldn't figure out is how to pass the `%%D` variable from the loop directly to the `COPY` command. That's why I'm using `PUSHD` and `POPD`, but that just feels dirty...

Comment: You could try putting `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` instead of just `SETLOCAL`. I don't know if it will work though.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it didn't make a difference so I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IF statement appears to be correct. I tried it out (on Windows 7) with the IMDISK and FOR loop commented out and it worked just fine. Here is the batch I ran.

```
@ECHO OFF
::
SETLOCAL
::
IF "%USERNAME%" EQU "jdoe" (
    ECHO jdoe User Found
    REM IMDISK -a -s 32M -m #: -p "/FS:exFAT /Q /Y /V:MERGEABLES"
    REM FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D IN ('WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE "size=33538048" GET Name /format:value'^) DO (
    REM     COPY "\\WIN2K8R2-F-01\Remote Applications\Batches\Merge PDFs.lnk" "%%D\Merge PDFs.lnk"
    REM     GOTO End
    REM ^)
) ELSE (
    ECHO User Not Found
    REM IMDISK -a -s 256M -m #: -p "/FS:exFAT /Q /Y /V:RAMDRIVE"
    REM FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D IN ('WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE "size=268304384" GET Name /format:value'^) DO (
    REM     COPY "\\WIN2K8R2-F-01\Remote Applications\Batches\Archive Folders.lnk" "%%D\Archive Folders.lnk"
    REM     GOTO End
    REM ^)
)
::
:End
::
IF EXIST "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.exe" (
    REM "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.exe" "%SystemDrive%\BGInfo.bgi" /Timer:0 /AcceptEula /Silent
)
::
ENDLOCAL
```

Your IMDISK call seems pretty standard. Can't see anything wrong there but I did not have the ability to test it.

I would take a closer look at the FOR loop. In my experience, FOR loops are sensitive when you nest them in other blocks. I often get all kinds of weird results. Try pulling the FOR loop into a separate batch file to test it and work out any bugs.

If you can get the FOR loop to work in a separate batch file but still not in your IF ELSE statement, try setting up a CALL to a Label that contains the IMDISK and FOR loop statements. For some reason using a CALL statement handles the nesting better.

Here is a reference for using a CALL subroutine: http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1154761&seqNum=11

Comment: I rewrote my version and it pretty much looked like yours and it worked, but I discovered other issues that are unfortunately preventing me from going forward with it. I'll update my question about those.

Answer (score 4):

I'd remove all the carets before the close-parentheses if I were you.

The caret escapes the special meaning of the next character - it means 'this charater literally'

BTW - you can format

```
for /f ... in ('whatever...') do (
```

as

```
for /f ... in (
  'whatever...'
 ) do (
```

if you wish - might make it a little more readable...

Comment: I took your advice and split the `FOR` into a couple of lines. Definitely more legible.